# How integrate Smartsupp chat to a React Site (Gatsby)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chat

I want to integrate the smartsupp chat in my Gatsby site (React), but the site only give you the following code... For a better performance would add some 5sec wait before loading.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _smartsupp = _smartsupp || {};
  _smartsupp.key = "YOUR_SMARTSUPP_CODE";
  // ...
  // your configuration
  // ...
  window.smartsupp||(function(d) {
    var s,c,o=smartsupp=function(){ o._.push(arguments)};o._=[];
    s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];c=d.createElement('script');
    c.type='text/javascript';c.charset='utf-8';c.async=true;
    c.src='https://www.smartsuppchat.com/loader.js?';s.parentNode.insertBefore(c,s);
  })(document);
</script>
```

I could hardcode a <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `...` /> or put it inside the  tag and make this thing done but I think there's a better way to having as a component

Answer (score 0):

Copy `.cache/default-html.js` to `src/html.js`.
You can customise it code in  ....

> Inserting HTML into the <head>
> Anything you render in the html.js component will not be made “live”
> in the client like other components. If you want to dynamically update
> your <head> we recommend using [React Helmet](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet/)
> - [Gatsby Docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/custom-html/#inserting-html-into-the-head)